# making a filter on Sendmail to avoid sending large bulks of emails

Tags: sendmail, filter

I have sendmail on my SMTP server.
and sometimes our management asks my to send mailshot of 200K
the problem: some mail-servers recognize my server as a spammer and block me since i am sending large bulk in short time.
is there a way to make sendmail to send at most 500 email per hour to specific domain, and to keep others for the next hour to send another 500 emails and so on
for example to send 500 emails at most to @yahoo.com per hour.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - maybe - well OK, yes but it's horribly complicated - you'd need to enable queueing and control the selective flushing of the queues very precisely.

A better solution would be to add a milter which does all this automatically for you - e.g. [milter-limit](http://www.milter.info/sendmail/milter-limit/)

Answer (score 0):

You're tackling the problem at the wrong point. You should be solving this at the point where the emails are being generated, not at the MTA. Of course the real problem is that if you're sending out 200k emails at one time you're going to have a hard time convincing anyone, or any system, that you're not a spammer.